# How do i get the average of three pos_coordinates values?

Tags: python

```
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0

    while True:
        client_socket.send("loc\n")
        data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        pos_coordinates = data.split()

        if(not(pos_coordinates[-1] == "eom" and pos_coordinates[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screenw != int(pos_coordinates[2])):
            screenw = int(pos_coordinates[2])
            screenh = int(pos_coordinates[3])

        blalba(pos_coordinates)
```

How can i get the average of 3 pos_coordinates list values ?
For example if pos_coordinates[8] contains the value 345, i want to get the average of that value and use the averaged value. the reason i want to do this, is because i am getting noise from the image detected through the camera and i thought the best way to go about this is to get the average of the values in order to get the value that i want. Any examples on how to do this?

Comment: average of **N** numbers `a1,a2,a3..` is .. `(a1 + a2 + a3 ... + aN)/N`

Comment: What exactly doe you mean by getting the average of 345? A single number's average is by definition itself.

Comment: @Roland Smith its because lets say the server detects the image of an object and returns it's coordinate.due to noises in the image detection it returns the value of +2/-2 even if the object is stationary at point 345. i will have the possibility of getting values like 343, 346 even if the object is stationary at 345

Comment: The average of N position coordinates would be a position whose components are each the average of corresponding component of each of the N points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the average of the whole list;

```
average = float(sum(pos_coordinates))/len(pos_coordinates)
```

If you just want to get the average of a subset, use a slice;

```
subset = pos_coordinates[3:9]
average = float(sum(subset))/len(subset)
```

In python 3.x the explicit `float` conversion is not necessary anymore to get accurate division.